# Meses Sin Intereses en Stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe

tengo un problema al momento de querer integrar MSI de Stripe en mi tienda la cual tengo en WooCommerce, he visto la guia pero la verdad es que no le entiendo mucho.
SI alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y que lo haya resulto, me podria apoyar por favor!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta Meta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

El plugin de Stripe para WooCommerce actualmente (<strike>Octubre 2020</strike> Julio 2021) no tiene soporte para MSI. Escribenos un email a support-mx arroba stripe punto com y te avisaremos cuando esto cambie.